# vue watch can detect external js file attributes?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

> > An external js file that changes the value of a property by a click
> >       event, but how does it detect that this property has changed since the
> >       vue page used this property value?
>
> 1.External js

```
                var obj = {},initValue = true;
                Object.defineProperty(obj, "newKey", {
                  get: function () {
                    return initValue;
                  },
                  set: function (value) {
                    return initValue = value;
                  }
                });
                var con=function () {
                  document.getElementById('btncc').onclick = function () {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      console.log(obj.newKey)
                    }, 3000)
                   initValue = false;
                  }

                }
                export default {
                  con,obj
                }
            > 2.vue page
    > Change the style
        <input id="color" type="color" :class="obj ? 'transparent': 'transparent2'" :disabled ="obj"/>
             import Canvas from '../../Api/js'
              export default {
                name: 'HelloWorld',
                data () {
                  return {
                      obj:Canvas.obj.newKey
                  }
                },
                mounted () {
                  Canvas.con()
                  console.log(this.obj,'我是msg啊');
                },
                watch: {
                  [Canvas.obj.newKey] (val) {
                    if(val){
                      console.log(this.obj,'我改变了吗，');
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
```

> watch no effect.
>   Probably like this.
>    https://jsfiddle.net/qjwanglei/L5afz75t/3/

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear; can you please add some more information with examples?

Comment: ok，I will add it now

Comment: sorry，Poor english